# Creating alert notification if process stops touching file

Tags: shell-script, scripting, monitoring, touch

I have set up a very simple script so that I can test whether a process is running or not and if so then it will touch a file and everything will be fine. However if process is not running and file isn't touched then I want to be able to set up an alert.

**pgrep "sleep" >/dev/null && touch monitor.log**

This script is running in a crontab every minute. I need a way for it to alert if file has not been touched? Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a straightforward file modification time check; the complications mainly arise from the possibility of up to 86,400 alerts per day (usually over a long holiday weekend is when these sorts of thing break), and additional complications of whether or not the modification time checker (or cron, or the system...) are actually running, whether the host clock is correct (time skew on virts, BIOS clock coming up four years in the future, broken NTP, etc).

```
#!/bin/sh

# what we're checking for mtime changes straying from the current system time
MONITOR=foofile
THRESHOLD=60

# use mtime on this file to avoid frequent alert spam should the above stop
# being updated
LAST_ALERT=barfile
LAST_ALERT_THRESHOLD=60

NOW_MTIME=`date +%s`

absmtimedelta() {
    delta=`expr $NOW_MTIME - $1`
    # absolute delta, in the event the mtime is wrong on the other side of
    # the current time
    echo $delta | tr -d -
}

alertwithlesscronspam() {
    msg=$1
    if [ ! -f "$LAST_ALERT" ]; then
        # party like it's
        touch -t 199912312359 -- "$LAST_ALERT"
    fi
    # KLUGE this stat call is unportable, but that's shell for you
    last_mtime=`stat -c '%Y' -- "$LAST_ALERT"`
    last_abs_delta=`absmtimedelta $last_mtime`
    if [ $last_abs_delta -gt $LAST_ALERT_THRESHOLD ]; then
        # or here instead send smoke signals, carrier pigeon, whatever
        echo $msg
        touch -- "$LAST_ALERT"
        exit 1
    fi
}

if [ ! -r "$MONITOR" ]; then
    alertwithlesscronspam "no file alert for '$MONITOR'"
fi

MONITOR_MTIME=`stat -c '%Y' -- "$MONITOR"`
ABS_DELTA=`absmtimedelta $MONITOR_MTIME`

if [ $ABS_DELTA -gt $THRESHOLD ]; then
    alertwithlesscronspam "mtime alert for '$MONITOR': $ABS_DELTA > $THRESHOLD"
fi
```

Perhaps instead consider a [standard monitoring framework](https://github.com/kahun/awesome-sysadmin#monitoring), which may have support for file modification time checks or a plugin to do so, customizable alerting, metrics, better code than the above, etc.

Comment: Great response, thank you very much. I am fairly new to Linux so that script is a lot to decipher. Not quite sure what the delta bit does but it's very informative. I would much rather use an application to monitor but I've received a brief from a potential employer asking how it would be done this way. I just need to know the understanding of how it works really. But once again thank you.